# Change class and ID when a checkbox is clicked with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checked

I have a checkbox on a html page which, when its checked I want to change the ID of one div and the class of another.

This is the code that I wrote to do it:

HTML:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="x" value="1" class="home6" /> Check this</li>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    if ($('.home6').is(':checked')) {
       $('.hider2').addClass('.hiderx').removeClass('.hider2');
       $('#next1').attr('id','next4');
    };
};
```

However this has no effect on my HTML.

I have tried debugging in the console but it throws no errors.

I don't think the event is ever getting triggered as I have tried adding an alert into the if statement, however, having read the [documentation for the :checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) but this code seams to be right.

Comment: so where is your 'change event' code? BTW, you should never change attribute ID of an element, there is no reason to do it

Comment: You don't need the `.` in the `addClass` call parameter

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DNTrs/3).

Comment: fixed Vicko's sample: http://jsfiddle.net/DNTrs/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="x" value="1" class="home6" /> Check this</li>
```

And the respective jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.home6').on('change', function() { 
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            $('.hider2').addClass('hiderx').removeClass('hider2');
            $('#next1').prop('id', 'next4');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be having a `change` OR `click` event binded to your checkbox to execute your script.

and in you code dot(.) in `addClass` and `removeClass` is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$(function(){
  $($('.home6').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('.hider2').addClass('hiderx').removeClass('hider2');
       $('#next1').attr('id','next4');
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: The `.` characters in your `addClas()` and `removeClass()` are superfluous. You also have an erroneous jQuery function in there too (e.g. `$($(`).

Answer (score 0):

It is working: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/KK2Xr/

```
if ($('.home6').is(':checked')) {
    $('.hider2').addClass('hiderx').removeClass('hider2');
    $('#next1').attr('id','next4');
};
```

How are you calling the function? You need to make that an action handler or call it on document.ready as it is in the fiddle.